# using ruby to test if a directory is writable?

Tags: ruby

Using ruby how can i test if a directory is writable?

There is a command:
 `FileUtils.writable?(file_name)`

That test if a file is writable.

Does it do it for directories as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the command :

```
File.writable?(directory_path)
```

does in fact validate if a directory is writable.

so this works for rubys 1.9.3 +

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File/Stat.html#method-i-writable-3F)?

Comment: that may work as well. especially for 1.9.3 . I found [this](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-writable-3F)
for 2.2.0 which worked for me using ruby 2.1.0

Comment: @graeme the definition of `File::writable?` is the same in `1.9.3` as well.